# Jquery mobile listview css on pageshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I try to load a json file and and put the content in a
**listview with flipswitches at the right side.**

My HTML file with one example listview line, which is working fine
(here without the first page and navbar to keep it clearly)

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="liststyle.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="pagetwo">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="main">   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="alarmlist">
      <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <a href="#pageone">Control</a>
        <select id="test-slider" data-role="slider" name="testslider">
          <option value="off">off</option>
          <option value="on">on</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and the linked liststyle.css

```
.ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li {
    display: block !important;
    padding: 0,9em 75px 0,9em 15px !important;
}
div.ui-slider-switch {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 40%;
    top: 12.5%;
}
```

and the code in the script.js file

```
$("#pagetwo").on("pageshow" , function() {

            var output = '';
            for (var x in data.alarm) {
                output += '<li data-role="fieldcontain">' +
                    '<a href="#">' + data["alarm"][x]["time"] + 
                '<select data-role="slider">' + 
                '<option value="off">off</option>' +
                '<option value="on">on</option></select>' +
                '</a> </li>';

            }
            $('#alarmlist').append(output).listview("refresh");
});
```

Now i get this result:
http://imageshack.com/a/img540/3844/dxuopI.png

When i delete the `.on("pageshow" , function() {` and run both pages from start,
i get a bit better result but also an error.
http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9508/89jtvd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to tell jQM to enhance the flipswitch as well as refreshing the list (`$('#alarmlist').append(output).listview("refresh").enhanceWithin();`):

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#pagetwo", function () {
    var output = '';
    for (var x in data.alarm) {
        output += '<li data-role="fieldcontain">' +
            '<a href="#">' + data["alarm"][x]["time"] +
            '</a> <select data-role="slider">' +
            '<option value="off">off</option>' +
            '<option value="on">on</option></select>' +
            '</li>';

    }
    $('#alarmlist').append(output).listview("refresh").enhanceWithin();
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/sksc8y53/)**